# Python or Shell assistance: How to search for a word and replace only the value next to it

Tags: python, shell

I have a text file (list.txt) with the following format:

```
Apple 1
Banana 5.0
orange_1 0.5
```

The list can go on for many lines. I would like to ultimately search for the word "Apple" and only replace the value next to it. I know how to use a "sed" command that can search and replace a word but I don't know how I can search for a word and replace only the value next to it?

the sed command I use in my script is a s follows:

```
sed "s/Apple/$1/g" list.txt > newlist.txt
```

where $1 is defined in a run script and could be anything (e.g. grape). Again this would switch the word Apple and not the value next to it. I would like to be able to perform this action either by using a SHELL or Python command. Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: `import re` and `re.sub('Apple [\d\.]+', 'Apple 12.34', 'Apple 1')`. Or use a positive lookback for `'Apple'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each line starts with the key and the value is the rest of the line after a space, you can use the following `sed` command to replace only the value:

```
sed "s/\(^Apple \)\(.*$\)/\1$1/"
```

Please note that this might be a fragile/insecure solution depending on the replacement value, e.g. if `$1` contains `/`, it can be used for a command insertion like `/;d;s//`.

A more robust solution with `awk`:

```
awk -v new="$1" '{print ($1 == "Apple") ? ($1 " " new) : $0}'
```

**UPD.** Both commands can work with files either directly or via standard streams:

```
sed ... file.txt > new.txt
cat file.txt | sed ... | cat > new.txt
```

(do not use `cat` like this, it's here to show piped input/output). Additionally, some versions of `sed` have option `-i` to change file *in place:*

```
sed -i ... file.txt
```

Comment: can I simply type this on a command line? also, where do you specify "list.txt" so the action can be performed on that file?

Comment: sed and cat are working!!! Thank you! I was unable to get the awk to work properly. I tried: awk -v new="$1" '{print ($1 == Apple") ? ($1 " " new) : $0}' list.txt > newlist.txt                             where $0 can be replace by any value

Comment: @user7649922 `$1` (first field) and `$0` (full line) inside `awk` script are not the same as `$1` (first argument) in the shell script. See `man awk` for details. Also double check the quotes, in your comment: `Apple"` should be `"Apple"`.

Answer (score 2):

Here I show positive lookback way as @ryugie said:

```
content = '''Apple 1
Banana 5.0
orange_1 0.5'''


def my_replace(content, fruit, value):
    import re
    return re.sub(r'(?<=' + fruit + ' )([\d\.]+)', str(value), content)


print my_replace(content, 'Apple', 4.0)

print my_replace(content, 'Banana', 1.5)
```

And we can get:

```
Apple 4.0
Banana 5.0
orange_1 0.5

Apple 1
Banana 1.5
orange_1 0.5
```

Comment: This did not work out exactly as I thought. The file "list.txt" contains the information for Apple, Banana and orange. I notice that you have to use "content =" which is another approach but I need the file "list.txt" to be updated. Also the output data looks a little muddled up for Banana.  Looking to have the text file (list.txt) to be updated or to saved as "newlist.txt" with the new information.